# Improve performance of Aggregate query on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, lambda

I have a big problem with aggregate framework of mongodb. I will try to explain the situation the best that I can, but the code is very clear.

We have a collection categories and notes, each note has a category id field and createdAt field, and we want to get the last note by each category.

So, we make the next agreggate function:

```
(async () =>{
        //busco las categorias
        const categoryCollection = db.collection('category');
        const categoryList  = await categoryCollection.find({},{ projection:{name: 1} }).toArray();

        //genero un arrays de ids de categoria
        const categoryIds = categoryList.map(function(e) { 
            return e._id;
        });

        //busco una nota por categoria ordenadas por fecha de creacion de forma descendente
        const articlesColl = db.collection('note');
        const articles = await articlesColl.aggregate([
            { $match: { "category":{$in: categoryIds }}},
            { $sort: { createdAt: -1 }},
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$category",
                    note: { $first: "$$ROOT"}
                }
            },
            { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$note" } },
            { $project : { _id : 1 ,title : 1, image : 1, category:1} },
            { $skip: skip},
            { $limit : limit }
        ],{allowDiskUse: true}).toArray();

        callback(null, success(
            //reemplazo los category id con el nombre
            articles.map(
                function(doc){
                    doc.categoryName = categoryList.find( e => e._id.equals(doc.category)).name;
                    return doc;
                }
            )
        ));
```

This query, gets the last note by each category but the performance of this "sucks".

I use mongo atlas and the alerts show me this:

> QUERY INEFFICIENCY SCORE: 258393, EXECUTION COUNT 4, AVERAGE EXECUTION
>   TIME 2872 MS

And this is an example of the query.

0: Object
$match: Object
category: Object
$in: Array[23]
0: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a60
1: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a55
2: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a53
3: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a66
4: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a5a
5: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a56
6: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a51
7: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a58
8: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a5b
9: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a57
10: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a63
11: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a5d
12: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a5c
13: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a59
14: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a52
15: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a5e
16: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a65
17: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a61
18: 5b202ef5d03337b3a0227daf
19: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a64
20: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a62
21: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a5f
22: 5a4536cd920f3a5acdf33a54
1: Object
$sort: Object
createdAt: -1
2: Object
$group: Object
_id: $category
note: Object
$first: $$ROOT
3: Object
$replaceRoot: Object
newRoot: $note
4: Object
$project: Object
_id: 1
title: 1
image: 1
category: 1
5: Object
$skip: 0
6: Object
$limit: 8
Fri Aug 17 2018 10:11am
6283 ms
1033573 / 8nScanned / nReturned

The big problem here is this query is really slow, some times spend more than 6 seconds to finish.

Some ideas to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider your size of collections, use `$sort` in memory cost you too much processing time.

You should create index for your `createAt` field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already have the Index for createdAt field, and the query   is taking more than 6 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

That query inefficiency score means that for every document you return the query examines 258393 documents.

Have you considered iterating the categoryList and using find to get just the most recent note?

```
const articles = categoryList.map(function(e) { 
            return await articlesColl.Find(x => x.category == e._id).Sort({ createdAt: -1 }).Limit(1)
        });
```

If you created an index on {category:1, createdAt:-1}, running this would require examining only a single document for each category (total of 23 in your example).  Even with the additional network round trips, reducing the number of documents examined by a factor of 100,000 should allow them all to complete in significantly less that 6 seconds.